# General solution to the following Bernoulli equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find the general solution to the following Bernoulli equation?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{t} + \frac{1}{x^2}, ∀ t ∈ I = (0,+∞)$$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $y={ x }^{ 3 }$ in order to become a linear dif.eq.I do hope i could explain it clearly $$\frac { dx }{ dt } =\frac { x }{ t } +{ x }^{ -2 }\quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac { { x }^{ 2 }dx }{ dt } =\frac { { x }^{ 3 } }{ t } +1\quad \Rightarrow y={ x }^{ 3 } $$

$$\frac { dy }{ 3dt } =\frac { y }{ t } +1\Rightarrow \frac { dy }{ 3dt } -\frac { y }{ t } =1\Rightarrow \frac { dy }{ 3dt } -\frac { y }{ t } =0\Rightarrow \frac { dy }{ 3y } =\frac { dt }{ t } $$
$$\int { \frac { dy }{ 3y }  } =\int { \frac { dt }{ t }  } \Rightarrow \frac { \ln { \left| y \right|  }  }{ 3 } =\ln { \left| t \right| +C } \Rightarrow y=C{ t }^{ 3 }\Rightarrow $$
$$\\ \frac { dy }{ dt } =\frac { tdC\left( t \right)  }{ dt } +3t^{ 2 }C\left( t \right) \Rightarrow \frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( \frac { tdC\left( t \right)  }{ dt } +3t^{ 2 }C\left( t \right)  \right) -C\left( t \right) { t }^{ 2 }=1\Rightarrow $$
$$\int { dC\left( t \right)  } =3\int { \frac { dt }{ t }  } =3\ln { \left| t \right| +C } \Rightarrow C\left( t \right) =3\ln { \left| t \right| +C } \Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow y={ t }^{ 3 }\left( 3\ln { \left| t \right| +C }  \right) $$
so the final answer is

> $${ x }^{ 3 }={ t }^{ 3 }\left( 3\ln { \left| t \right| +C }  \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Change of variables $ x = -y^{1/3}$ gives you a linear differential equation.

Comment: see alos here https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjj3d2xzM3MAhWHQBQKHUPsCsEQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorial.math.lamar.edu%2FClasses%2FDE%2FBernoulli.aspx&usg=AFQjCNGSdV-x-hNZmRHY2gPk9e7OnWUn_A